# How to solve TransactionTooLargeException error?

Tags: android

i getting this TransactionTooLargeException when i clicked selected cell of my listview, please can any one guide me how to solve this...?

My Error log is:-

```
Exception when starting activity   com.app.Login/com.app.New_Site_Risk_Assessment.Show_Selected_Images
10- android.os.TransactionTooLargeException
at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)

at android.app.ApplicationThreadProxy.scheduleLaunchActivity(ApplicationThreadNative.java:660)

at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.realStartActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:615)

at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.startSpecificActivityLocked
at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.resumeTopActivityLocked
at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.completePauseLocked
at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.activityPaused
at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.activityPaused(ActivityManagerService.java:4131)

at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:371)

at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:1548)
at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:338)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
Force removing ActivityRecord{41261b98 com.app.Login/com.app.New_Site_Risk_Assessment.Show_Selected_Images}: app died, no saved state

Force removing ActivityRecord{413329a8 com.app.Login/com.app.Qoute_Inbox.Qoute_Inbox_Display_Data}: app died, no saved state
```

Comment: When you click on the cell, does this generate a call to `startActivity()`? If so, post the code for that. I'm guessing that you are putting too many bytes of extras in your Intent when you start the activity.

Comment: yes...i passed three base64 String to another activity....

Comment: There is a limit to the amount of data that you can put in an Intent. How much data are you trying to pass?

Comment: I've answered a similar issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73008611/2860701

Answer (score 0):

**When sending data via an intent, you should be careful to limit the data size to a few KB**.

Sending too much data can cause the system to throw a TransactionTooLargeException exception.

Comment: so how to resolve ths issue