# Why getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages() will make application crash

Tags: android

My App have a code segment that get installed applications in phone. and I use the getInstalledPackages API. and I found this will make my application crash and I will get `java.lang.RuntimeException: Package manager has died`.

My question is why it it happened and how to solve it(to get installed applications) by this way or other way?

this is one of the reports:

```
at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getApplicationInfo(ApplicationPackageManager.java:224)
at com.baidu.location.ae.a(Unknown Source)
at com.baidu.location.LocationClient.getAccessKey(Unknown Source)
at com.baidu.location.LocationClient.cy(Unknown Source)
at com.baidu.location.LocationClient.do(Unknown Source)
at com.baidu.location.LocationClient$a.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5050)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:805)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:621)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.os.DeadObjectException
at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub$Proxy.getApplicationInfo(IPackageManager.java:1740)
at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getApplicationInfo(ApplicationPackageManager.java:219)
```

Comment: Sharing code snippet will help us to understand what you did wrong

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Package manager has died with TransactionTooLargeException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24253976/android-package-manager-has-died-with-transactiontoolargeexception)

Answer (score 1):

Following is the code to get the list of `activities/applications` installed on Android :

```
final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
final List pkgAppsList = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities( mainIntent, 0);
```

You will get all the necessary data in the `ResolveInfo` to start a application. You can check `ResolveInfo javadoc` [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ResolveInfo.html).

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but this method clearly will not work at the same condition.We all are using PackageManager while package manger has die..

Answer (score 0):

It is failing for me after a bad Samsung S23 OS update:

After OS upgrade on my Verizon Galaxy S23  256 gig,many apps including Samsungs keyboard and play store keep crashing.   Most frequent, (continuous in the background), crash is:

txpoweradmin has stopped

08:50:36.214  E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main

```
             Process: .qms, PID: 8606

             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service vendor.qti.data.txpwradmin.StxPwrService: android.os.BadParcelableException: Failure retrieving array; only received 679 of 789
```

...

Caused by: android.os.BadParcelableException: Failure retrieving array; only received 679 of 789

...

Caused by: android.os.DeadObjectException: Transaction failed on small parcel; remote process probably died, but this could also be caused by running out of binder buffer space

...

at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub$Proxy.getInstalledPackages(IPackageManager.java:5623)
at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getInstalledPackagesAsUser(ApplicationPackageManager.java:1267)

...

Google play crashes shortly after I open it.  Galaxy Store won't open.  I had no keyboard until I disabled Samsung's I had been using and switched to gboard.  I think I will likely have to factory reset the device.

It was this Software update that broke everything:

Software update history

Software updated to S911USQU1BWK4

Applied - December 1, 2023 at 6:34 AM