# TransactionTooLargeException

Tags: android

These simple lines of code get me a `TransactionTooLargeException`. In the same function, in another conditional branch, I have another dialog, which works perfectly. I am at a complete loss. Can you suggest anything?

Thank you

```
AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);              
b.setTitle(R.string.choose_winner);
AlertDialog dialog = b.create();
dialog.show();
```

Here is the log, sorry I omited its inclusion the first time.

> 11-08 19:20:12.455: E/AndroidRuntime(1431): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>
> 11-08 19:20:12.455: E/AndroidRuntime(1431):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Adding window failed
>
> 11-08 19:20:12.455: E/AndroidRuntime(1431):   at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:491)
>
> 11-08 19:20:12.455: E/AndroidRuntime(1431):   at
>   android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:301)
>
> 11-08 19:20:12.455: E/AndroidRuntime(1431):   at
>   android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:215)
>
> 11-08 19:20:12.455: E/AndroidRuntime(1431):   at
>   android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:140)
>
> 11-08 19:20:12.455: E/AndroidRuntime(1431):   at
>   android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:537)
>
> 11-08 19:20:12.455: E/AndroidRuntime(1431):   at
>   android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:278)
>
> 11-08 19:20:12.455: E/AndroidRuntime(1431):   at
>   com.sebmag.acquiroid.GameActivity.play(GameActivity.java:442)
>
> 11-08 19:20:12.455: E/AndroidRuntime(1431):   at
>   com.sebmag.acquiroid.GameActivity$PlayView.onTouch(GameActivity.java:126)
>
> 11-08 19:20:12.455: E/AndroidRuntime(1431):   at
>   android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:5536)
>
> 11-08 19:20:12.455: E/AndroidRuntime(1431):   at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1957)
>
> 11-08 19:20:12.455: E/AndroidRuntime(1431):   at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1726)
>
> 11-08 19:20:12.455: E/AndroidRuntime(1431):   at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1957)
>
> 11-08 19:20:12.455: E/AndroidRuntime(1431):   at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1726)
>
> 11-08 19:20:12.455: E/AndroidRuntime(1431):   at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1957)
>
> 11-08 19:20:12.455: E/AndroidRuntime(1431):   at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1726)
>
> 11-08 19:20:12.455: E/AndroidRuntime(1431):   at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1957)
>
> 11-08 19:20:12.455: E/AndroidRuntime(1431):   at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1726)
>
> 11-08 19:20:12.455: E/AndroidRuntime(1431):   at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1912)
>
> 11-08 19:20:12.455: E/AndroidRuntime(1431):   at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1371)
>
> 11-08 19:20:12.455: E/AndroidRuntime(1431):   at
>   android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2364)
>
> 11-08 19:20:12.455: E/AndroidRuntime(1431):   at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1860)
>
> 11-08 19:20:12.455: E/AndroidRuntime(1431):   at
>   android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:5721)
>
> 11-08 19:20:12.455: E/AndroidRuntime(1431):   at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:2890)
>
> 11-08 19:20:12.455: E/AndroidRuntime(1431):   at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2466)
>
> 11-08 19:20:12.455: E/AndroidRuntime(1431):   at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.processInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:845)
>
> 11-08 19:20:12.455: E/AndroidRuntime(1431):   at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2475)
>
> 11-08 19:20:12.455: E/AndroidRuntime(1431):   at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>
> 11-08 19:20:12.455: E/AndroidRuntime(1431):   at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>
> 11-08 19:20:12.455: E/AndroidRuntime(1431):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4575)
>
> 11-08 19:20:12.455: E/AndroidRuntime(1431):   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>
> 11-08 19:20:12.455: E/AndroidRuntime(1431):   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>
> 11-08 19:20:12.455: E/AndroidRuntime(1431):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
>
> 11-08 19:20:12.455: E/AndroidRuntime(1431):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
>
> 11-08 19:20:12.455: E/AndroidRuntime(1431):   at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>
> 11-08 19:20:12.455: E/AndroidRuntime(1431): Caused by:
>   android.os.TransactionTooLargeException
>
> 11-08 19:20:12.455: E/AndroidRuntime(1431):   at
>   android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
>
> 11-08 19:20:12.455: E/AndroidRuntime(1431):   at
>   android.view.IWindowSession$Stub$Proxy.add(IWindowSession.java:516)
>
> 11-08 19:20:12.455: E/AndroidRuntime(1431):   at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:481)
>
> 11-08 19:20:12.455: E/AndroidRuntime(1431):   ... 33 more
>
> 11-08 19:20:12.650: E/AndroidRuntime(1431): Error reporting crash
>
> 11-08 19:20:12.650: E/AndroidRuntime(1431):
>   android.os.DeadObjectException
>
> 11-08 19:20:12.650: E/AndroidRuntime(1431):   at
>   android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
>
> 11-08 19:20:12.650: E/AndroidRuntime(1431):   at
>   android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.handleApplicationCrash(ActivityManagerNative.java:2867)
>
> 11-08 19:20:12.650: E/AndroidRuntime(1431):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:72)
>
> 11-08 19:20:12.650: E/AndroidRuntime(1431):   at
>   java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
>
> 11-08 19:20:12.650: E/AndroidRuntime(1431):   at
>   java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
>
> 11-08 19:20:12.650: E/AndroidRuntime(1431):   at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: could we see the log? methinks something else is going on.

Comment: i found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11451393/what-to-do-on-transactiontoolargeexception/12809171#12809171" this but it doesn't seem to be terribly related. this is beyond my experience.

Comment: I was caught in an infinite loop, sorry again for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was other than what I thought. Namely I was caught in an infinite while loop.
Question closed, shame +1.

Answer (score 1):

I can see you solved your problem :) but let me write couple of lines for other lost souls having this problem I also had couple of day ago.

It turns out my problem was trying to move a large graph of objects between activities. There is a 1MB limit on data being transferred and the limit is even smaller in real life. I've solved the issue by reverting to good old java serialization instead of using Parcelable via Parceler library. More info in this [blog post](https://medium.com/nemanja-kovacevic/yet-another-post-on-serializable-vs-parcelable-1e829e98472).