# Android TransactionTooLargeException in crash reports

Tags: android, parse-platform

We are using Crittercism (https://www.crittercism.com/) and are getting a few crash reports on both the Verizon Galaxy S3 and Sprint Galaxy S3 with the following stack trace:

```
0   java.lang.RuntimeException: Adding window failed
1       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:681)
2       at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:345)
3       at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:224)
4       at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:149)
5       at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:552)
6       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2702)
7       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
8       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:143)
9       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1241)
10      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4950)
13      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
14      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
15      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
16      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
17      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
18  Caused by: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException
19      at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
20      at android.view.IWindowSession$Stub$Proxy.add(IWindowSession.java:545)
21      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:670)
22      ... 16 more
23  android.os.TransactionTooLargeException
24      at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
25      at android.view.IWindowSession$Stub$Proxy.add(IWindowSession.java:545)
26      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:670)
27      at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:345)
28      at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:224)
29      at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:149)
30      at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:552)
31      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2702)
32      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
33      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:143)
34      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1241)
35      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
36      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
37      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4950)
38      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
39      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
40      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
41      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
42      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The only part where it traces back to our code is on the query.find() line for a Parse.com query that looks like:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>(
                    "CustomTab");
            query.setCachePolicy(ParseQuery.CachePolicy.NETWORK_ELSE_CACHE);
            List<ParseObject> list = null;
            ParseObject object = null;
            try {
                list = query.find();
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Anyone have any ideas? Is this maybe something else on the Galaxy S3 that is being picked up unrelated to my app?

Comment: Have you checked this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11451393/what-to-do-on-transactiontoolargeexception)?

Comment: Not really sure what would cause it. Why does the S3 out of every Android device do it? What is it from? Is it just from an unrelated app on their phone rather than mine?