# error receiving huge data over socket in android Jelly Bean & Kitkat

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I have an application that connects to a java server and receive a list of names and thumbnail images. It worked correctly in all android versions until Jelly Bean &  Kitkat. I get a weird error with no exception and no tracing:

```
01-08 16:08:30.587  13412-13412/com.sefryek_tadbir.trading A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 13412 (_tadbir.trading)
01-08 16:08:31.168      616-659/system_process E/InputDispatcher﹕ channel '418a8330 com.sefryek_tadbir.trading/com.sefryek_tadbir.trading.view.activity.authenticate.LoginActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
01-08 16:08:31.168      616-659/system_process E/InputDispatcher﹕ channel '41b281b0 com.sefryek_tadbir.trading/com.sefryek_tadbir.trading.view.activity.authenticate.LoginActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
```

I use **ACM** library (**ACMConnectionHandler** class) for connecting over socket, and get the error somewhere after calling startConnection() method, even in debug mode I can't find the line which error came from.
I also read this similar thread but got no help: 
[What to do on TransactionTooLargeException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11451393/what-to-do-on-transactiontoolargeexception)

any ideas?
thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was the GifView (a Custom View to show gif resource)!! I was showing a gif image when AsyncTask does it job in background. GifView worked fine before jelly bean! I'm confused whats' wrong with it!