# android.os.TransactionTooLargeException thrown randomly

Tags: android, parcelable

I am seeing quite a few error reports from one of my live apps, the caused is this exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Adding window failed
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:513)
   at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:259)
   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2852)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2250)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)

Caused by: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException
   at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java)
   at android.view.IWindowSession$Stub$Proxy.addToDisplay(IWindowSession.java:683)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:502)
   at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:259)
   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2852)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2250)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

From what I've read [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/TransactionTooLargeException.html), I believe the cause may be down to a too large `Parcelable` I am adding to an `Intent` extras. I am currently passing an Object from one Activity to another, in that Objects `writeToParcel` method I am saving a JSON String which ranges in size from 1000 - 1500 characters in length. Could this be the cause?

Whilst testing the app I sometimes notice the UI lags as though it is low on memory, freezes and then force closes.

Would it be better to pass the Object from one Activity to another using static variables or could this be caused by something else entirely?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this can very well be caused by a too large Parcelable, too large object graph to be sent as a Parcelable to be exact. In my experience you're better off using java serialization if you're transferring large graph and that is pretty much the opposite of the advice you'll get elsewhere on SO and in general. To be fair it's better than using Parcelable via Parceler lib, I've never used pure Parcelable. For more details see [my blog post](https://medium.com/nemanja-kovacevic/yet-another-post-on-serializable-vs-parcelable-1e829e98472) on this topic.

Answer (score 1):

according [What to do on TransactionTooLargeException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11451393/what-to-do-on-transactiontoolargeexception) :

This can occur, when you pass lot of data through intent extras

If possible, split the big operation in to small chunks, for example, instead of calling applyBatch() with 1000 operations, call it with 100 each.

Do not exchange huge data (>1Mb) between services and application

> 1Mb According http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/TransactionTooLargeException.html

Comment: i think the limit is 1Mb

Comment: @Arash -Oh! - i think you said right - according this source : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/TransactionTooLargeException.html

Comment: Good answer, but next time quote the text that you copy 1:1.

Answer (score 1):

Do you override

```
onSaveInstanceState()
```

if you do check what you are saving there could also be an error.
Like if you do

```
outState.putParcelable("key", outState); //Error is passing the bundle
```