# Android: Device hang forever ( TransactionTooLargeException )

Tags: android

It will happen when I open my application then press home button and open other applications then come back to my application. I cannot get any strange log or put any breakpoint to see what happen in there. Only the Device Window in Eclipse show me like this.
    (those all black marks are my application package name)

[image: error]

I'm not so sure if it relate with how I manage the saveInstanceState of Fragment and Activity or not but I can show you my codes.

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    savedInstanceState.putBoolean("isSplashShown", isSplashShown);

}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        isSplashShown = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("isSplashShown");
        this.savedInstanceState = savedInstanceState;
    }

}
```

**Edit:**
After trying so many time I got error logs:

```
!!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
Exception in new application when starting activity <myapplication package>/.<my activity>
android.os.TransactionTooLargeException
at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
at android.app.ApplicationThreadProxy.scheduleLaunchActivity(ApplicationThreadNative.java:710)
at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.realStartActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:702)
at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.attachApplicationLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:4117)
at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.attachApplication(ActivityManagerService.java:4195)
at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:357)
at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:1633)
at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:367)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

Comment: Instead show your `onCreate()` code

Answer (score 0):

According to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11451393/what-to-do-on-transactiontoolargeexception). I just found that I put a long json string (Converted from object to json String) to Intent and send it to Next Activity. So my solution is to make the class of that object to be Parcelable and then the problem is gone.