# Why does Android N throw TransactionTooLargeException when using Bundles?

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat

On Android N whenever I pass some binary or large data in bundle I get a `TransactionTooLargeException`, however it runs without issues on android M and below.

How can I solve this?

Comment: @VivekMishra this tries to solve the question not just state why it happens so not a duplicate

Comment: To add to the already existing answer i am posting a link to the blog that has a sample code http://blog.sqisland.com/2016/09/transactiontoolargeexception-crashes-nougat.html

Comment: @Raghunandan you are free to edit the answer and add that link

Comment: @ColdFire its just an link. Its better to post the content of the blog as the link  might die in the future.

Comment: @Raghunandan yes i mean you are free to add that content too

Comment: @ColdFire its better you do it cause some people reviewing might reject the same( if they don't understand the edit. they might think its not relevant). I am not sure that depends on the rep though

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There has been a behavior change in Android N

Quoting [the docs](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html#other):

> Many platform APIs have now started checking for large payloads being
>   sent across `Binder` transactions, and the system now rethrows
>   `TransactionTooLargeExceptions` as `RuntimeExceptions`, instead of
>   silently logging or suppressing them. One common example is storing
>   too much data in `Activity.onSaveInstanceState()`, which causes
>   `ActivityThread.StopInfo` to throw a `RuntimeException` when your app
>   targets `Android 7.0`.

**Note**: Apps targeting M or below won't throw the exception, they will just silently log or suppress them

## How to solve this:

Rethink why you need so much data in bundle in the first place.

1. If it is binary data or a bitmap, it is best to store it in a file and pass the path in the bundle.
2. If you are passing too many objects

   - You can use libraries like `Otto`,`EventBus` to avoid it.
   - Just pass the necessary info required for constructing the Object once again.
   - Create a singleton class and set the data there and access it in another Activity or Fragment from there.

Comment: So in other words, it was always failing, it just didn't crash?

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede yes as the docs said