# stackoverflow error on view drag drop update

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, view, viewgroup

I am using `ondragListener` for view drag . My root is `viewgroup` with more `viewgroup` containers into the root and am adding views like `imageview/textview` inside the containers .

If I use the only container(`ViewGroup`) like `linearlayout` for drag and drop its working fine but if I start adding views like `imageview` inside these containers and still dragging point is containers only holding this view.

`onActionDrop` gets an `stackoverflow error : stack size 8MB`.

`onActionDrop` code is :

```
if (e.getAction()==DragEvent.ACTION_DROP) {
        final View view = (View) e.getLocalState();
        final ViewGroup from = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
        from.removeView(view);
        final LinearLayout toView = (LinearLayout) v;
        toView.addView(view);}
```

Error Logs :

```
 java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB
    android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:6546)
    android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 26840220 bytes
android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:503)
android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.handleApplicationCrash(ActivityManagerNative.java:4425)
com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:90)
java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
```

Comment: Is this a full stacktrace?

Comment: Your code seems right but the problem may be with the amount of visual components you´re moving from one container to the other, you may need to destroy and recreate the dragged view or something like that. Please see this other issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11451393/what-to-do-on-transactiontoolargeexception

Comment: @TinTran Yes this is it.

Comment: Can you show the full code, where you assign the `DragListener` to the `Views`,  and the code for the `DragListener` itself?

Comment: I think you may have a cycle in your View hierarchy.  A stack overflow on `resetResolvedLayoutDirection` often indicates this.  This can happen for a variety of reasons (many documented here at SO if you search), depending on how you create/inflate them.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be looking at the `TransactionTooLarge` exception instead of the StackOverflow one. TransactionTooLarge can sometimes be a hard one to track down but usually it has something to do with too much data being sent between `Activity`/`Fragment` or stored in `savedInstanceState`. As pointed out by @eduyayo in a comment above, you could take a look at this post:

[What to do on TransactionTooLargeException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11451393/what-to-do-on-transactiontoolargeexception)

I experienced a similar error a while back and it was due to a huge list was being passed from an Activity to a Fragment and the crash itself occurred in a completely random place.