# IntentService onCreate() called but onHandleIntent() not

Tags: java, android, android-service, intentservice

I'm starting an `IntentService` with the following method:

```
private void startMyService(Data data) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
    intent.putExtra(KEY_DATA, data.toJson());
    startService(intent);
}
```

The `Data` class:

```
public class Data extends ArrayList<MyObject> {

    public Data() {
        super();
    }

    public Data(Collection<MyObject> myObjects) {
        super(myObjects);
    }

    public String toJson() {
        return new Gson().toJson(this);
    }

    public static Data fromJson(String jsonString) {
        return new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, Data.class);
    }
}
```

The relevant part of the `IntentService`:

```
public class MyService extends IntentService {

    private Data data;

    public MyService() {
        super("myServiceName");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        // this gets called properly
        Log.d("myTag", "Service onCreate()");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        // this is not called in case of the bigger dataset
        Log.d("myTag", "Service onHandleIntent()");

        String dataJson = intent.getStringExtra(KEY_DATA);
        data = Data.fromJson(dataJson);

        // doing stuff with data
    }
}
```

I have 2 test scenarios:

- Data holds 2000 objects
- Data holds 4000 objects

With 2000 objects, the `Service` runs flawlessly.

With 4000 objects, the `onCreate()` method of the `Service` is called and that's it... `onHandleIntent()` is not called. The app just throws an ANR after a while.

I've tested with both `Log.d()` calls and breakpoints on the first line of `onHandleIntent()`, it is not called at all when `Data` holds 4000 objects.

`TransactionTooLargeException` is **not** thrown.

I get no `Exception`s thrown at all, no idea what's wrong.

What could be the cause of this behaviour?

Comment: Try to save json in the sqlite so that you can direcly access it by calling method from intentService class

Comment: may be this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14379016/5015207) will be helpful: it seems there will not always be a TransactionTooLargeException if the Binder transaction fails

Answer (score 0):

You may not see the `TransactionTooLargeException` if you are filtering the logcat. There is a reasonable limit to the amount of data that you can pass in an `Intent`. 4000 objects serialized to JSON is definitely too mucn! This is the wrong approach. Your application architecture is flawed.

You can simply store the 4000 objects in a `static` variable so that the `Service` can get to them without having to serialize them, pass them from `Activity` to `Service`, then deserialize them.

Alternatively, you need to serialize the 4000 objects to a file, or use a database to hold the data.