# Unfortunately Application has stopped after a couple of hours

Tags: java, android

```
11-04 13:15:53.340 28940-28940/com.xxxxx.xxxx E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
11-04 13:15:53.360 28940-28940/com.xxxxx.xxxx E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
             java.lang.RuntimeException: Adding window failed
                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:491)
                 at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:301)
                 at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:215)
                 at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:140)
                 at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:537)
                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2507)
                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1986)
                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                 Caused by: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException
                 at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
                 at android.view.IWindowSession$Stub$Proxy.add(IWindowSession.java:516)
                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:481)
                 at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:301) 
                 at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:215) 
                 at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:140) 
                 at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:537) 
                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2507) 
                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1986) 
                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123) 
                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147) 
                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424) 
                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784) 
                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551) 
                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I get this error when i leave the app open for a few hours and come back to use it. I works perfectly if you keep using it. But if I leave it for a couple of hours and come back, It says Unfortunately the app has stopped.

I cannot figure out what's causing this.

Comment: `android.os.TransactionTooLargeException` you are putting too much stuff in a bundle, possibly in a savedInstanceState

Comment: @njzk2 but why would it happen only if i leave the app untouched for a few hours. If i keep using it, it will never stop. i'll have a look at what you are saying.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What to do on TransactionTooLargeException](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11451393/5221149).