# Android TransactionTooLarge Exception

Tags: android, transactions, runtime-error

Just started getting Below exception in android version 24 and above.
I have already gone through old related posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11451393/what-to-do-on-transactiontoolargeexception) but didn't get any specific reason. I have stuck since days as i am not using IPC as suggested in linked answer. I am not putting lenghty data except some strings in bundle while navigating between activities and fragments.
However i am using one Timer to update status after every 30 seconds via a handler. Guys please help me .

```
Exception java.lang.RuntimeException:
android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 540408 bytes
android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run (ActivityThread.java:3888)
android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:751)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6311)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run
(ZygoteInit.java:872)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:762)

Caused by android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size   
540408 bytes
android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative (BinderProxy.java)
android.os.BinderProxy.transact (BinderProxy.java:615)
android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.activityStopped       
(ActivityManagerProxy.java:3685)
android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run (ActivityThread.java:3880)
android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:751)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6311)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run   
(ZygoteInit.java:872)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:762)
```

Answer (score 0):

Intents, Content Providers, Messenger, all system services like Telephone, Vibrator etc. utilize IPC infrastructure provider by Binder.Moreover the activity lifecycle callbacks also use this infrastructure and 1MB is the overall limit on all the binder transactions executed in the system at a particular moment.

In your case,maybe there are lot of other operations/Binder transactions occurring in parallel which are using up the 1MB transaction limit