# TransactionTooLargeException in Nougat

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment, runtimeexception, tabactivity

Exception

```
 05-12 15:42:45.791 11043-11043/ E/UncaughtException: java.lang.RuntimeException: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 631792 bytes
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run(ActivityThread.java:3776)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
                                                                    Caused by: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 631792 bytes
                                                                       at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
                                                                       at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:615)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.activityStopped(ActivityManagerNative.java:3700)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run(ActivityThread.java:3768)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123) 
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867) 
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757) 
05-12 15:42:47.247 11043-11043/ E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                Process: , PID: 11043
                                                                java.lang.RuntimeException: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 631792 bytes
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run(ActivityThread.java:3776)
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
                                                                 Caused by: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 631792 bytes
                                                                    at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
                                                                    at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:615)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.activityStopped(ActivityManagerNative.java:3700)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run(ActivityThread.java:3768)
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123) 
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867) 
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
```

Fragment OnItemClick:-

```
 listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                long id) {

            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            ProdModel mProdModel = prodList.get(position);
            bundle.putSerializable("object", mProdModel);
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DetailActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("bundle", bundle);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

        }

    });
```

In DetailActivity,

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getBundleExtra("bundle");
    if (bundle != null) {
        ProdModel model = (ProdModel) bundle.getSerializable("object");
    }
```

DetailActivity Manifest,

```
  <activity
        android:name="com.mass.mysample.DetailActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```

Image Loading Using Picasso,

```
 Picasso.with(this).load(model.getImage())
             .placeholder(R.drawable.logo_without)
             .fit().into(productimage);
```

Model Class

```
public class ProdModel implements Serializable {
private String seller_id;
String name;
private String image;
private float price;
private float specialprice;
private String entity_id;
private String productNumQuantity;
private String storetitle;
private String description;
private String discount;
private String max_price;
private String store_name;
private String StoreUrl;

public String getProductNumQuantity() {
    return productNumQuantity;
}

public void setProductNumQuantity(String productNumQuantity) {
    this.productNumQuantity = productNumQuantity;
}

public String getDiscount() {
    return discount;
}

public void setDiscount(String discount) {
    this.discount = discount;
}

public String getMax_price() {
    return max_price;
}

public void setMax_price(String max_price) {
    this.max_price = max_price;
}

public String getStore_name() {
    return store_name;
}

public void setStore_name(String store_name) {
    this.store_name = store_name;
}

public String getStoreUrl() {
    return StoreUrl;
}

public void setStoreUrl(String storeUrl) {
    StoreUrl = storeUrl;
}

public String getStoretitle() {
    return storetitle;
}

public void setStoretitle(String storetitle) {
    this.storetitle = storetitle;
}

public String getSeller_id() {
    return seller_id;
}

public void setSeller_id(String seller_id) {
    this.seller_id = seller_id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(String image) {
    this.image = image;
}

public String getEntity_id() {
    return entity_id;
}

public void setEntity_id(String entity_id) {
    this.entity_id = entity_id;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public float getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(float price) {
    this.price = price;
}

public float getSpecialPrice() {
    return specialprice;
}

public void setSpecialPrice(float specialprice) {
    this.specialprice = specialprice;
}

}
```

Data flow from TabActivity to fragment,

```
1.I have a TabActivity with ViewPager and Fragment. 
2.In Fragment, I have a ListView.
3.The Data to fragment is passed from view pager adapter by set arguments.
```

Solutions I tried

```
1.A POJO class that implements Serialization. 
2.I use Picasso to load the image from image URL. 
3.This exception is thrown when OnItemClick on ListView in fragment passes data to DetailActivity to show all passed data.
4.I get this exception after the DetailActivity load's image and other data then app suddenly crashes.
5.I pass data in Intent was all POJO Object with Id, Name, Image URL, Price etc.,
```

Note:- 
App Crash only in **NOUGAT**

Finally, The fix I implemented

***changing the targetSdkVersion to 23 from 25***

After changing, my application not crashing in Nougat too.

All I have to Know is this proper solution or is there any workaround.

Please Guide to the proper way.

Thanks in advance.

Fragment

```
public class ProdFragment extends Fragment {
ListView listview;
SharedPreferences spref;
Boolean isInternetPresent = false;
ConnectionDetector cd;

private String toBeDisplayed,CatID;
private static final String TAG = ProdFragment.class.getSimpleName();
String totalProductCart;
private ArrayList<Root_SubCatModel> subCatList;
private ArrayList<ProdModel> prodList;
ProdAdapter adapter;

public ProdFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    spref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(getResources().getString(R.string.myPref),
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    if (bundle != null) {
        int tabPosition = bundle.getInt("Tab_Position");
        toBeDisplayed = bundle.getString("Tab_ToBeDisplayed");
        CatID = bundle.getString("CategoryId");
        subCatList = (ArrayList<Root_SubCatModel>) bundle.getSerializable("Tab_Data");
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.prod_listview, container, false);

    cd = new ConnectionDetector(getActivity());
    listview = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.prodlist);
    if (subCatList != null) {
        adapter = new ProdAdapter(getActivity(),
                CatID,
                toBeDisplayed,
                R.layout.list_product,
                subCatList,
                (ProductCartCountListener)getActivity());
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        prodList = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0; i<subCatList.size();i++){
            if (subCatList.get(i).getProd() != null) {
                if(toBeDisplayed.equals("SubCategory")){
                    if (CatID.equals(subCatList.get(i).getCategory_id())) {
                        this.prodList = subCatList.get(i).getProd();
                    }
                }else if(toBeDisplayed.equals("Products")) {
                    this.prodList = subCatList.get(i).getProd();
                }
            }
        }

    }

    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                long id) {

            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putSerializable("object", prodList.get(position));
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DetailActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("bundle", bundle);
            startActivityForResult(intent,1);
        }

    });

    return rootView;
}

public void showAlertDialog(Context context, String title, String message, Boolean status) {
    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();

    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle(title);

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage(message);

    // Setting alert dialog icon
    //alertDialog.setIcon((status) ? R.drawable.success : R.drawable.fail);

    // Setting OK Button
    alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        }
    });

    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Bundle b = data.getExtras();
            if (b != null) {
                ProdModel myobj = (ProdModel) b.getSerializable("Cart_Quantity");
                if (myobj != null) {
                    if (prodList != null) {
                        for (ProdModel P : prodList) {
                            if (P.getEntity_id().equals(myobj.getEntity_id())) {
                                P.setProductNumQuantity(myobj.getProductNumQuantity());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    Log.d(TAG,"Product_Id : " + myobj.getEntity_id()
                            + ", Product_Cart_Count : " + myobj.getProductNumQuantity());
                }
            }
        } else if (resultCode == 0) {
            Log.d(TAG,"RESULT CANCELLED");
        }
    }
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    String totalProductCart = spref.getString("Cart_Count_Tool", "0");
    Activity activity = getActivity();
    if(activity instanceof TabActivity){
        TabActivity myActivity = (TabActivity) activity;
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) myActivity.findViewById(R.id.back_toolbar);
        ImageView cart_imageview = (ImageView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.cart_imageview);
        cart_imageview.setImageDrawable(myActivity.buildCounterDrawable(
                Integer.parseInt(totalProductCart)));
    }
    Log.d(TAG,"RESULT NOTIFIED");
}

public void refreshData(String productId, boolean isAddAsyncTaskComplete,
                        boolean isAddAsyncTaskLimitReached, boolean isDeleteAsyncTaskComplete){
    adapter.setQuantityCount(prodList, productId, isAddAsyncTaskComplete,
            isAddAsyncTaskLimitReached, isDeleteAsyncTaskComplete);

}
```

TabActivity Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/storeimage"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/color_dark_blue"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/color_orange"/>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
 </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

ListView

```
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/prodlist"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Is it the full stacktrace ? I remember having this exception in a project, and the top stacktrace said "too large transaction" but when scrolling down, it was in fact caused by a stackOverflowException, because of a recursive call I accidentally made

Comment: Yes this is my full stacktrace

Comment: Can you post your `onSaveInstanceState()` implementations?

Comment: @azizbekian sorry I don't have any onSavedState() implementations.

Comment: Can u post the `DetailActivity` declaration in AndroidManifest.xml ? Btw, You should have use `Parcelable` instead of `Serializable`. I think switching to `Parcelable` will solve the problem

Comment: @TinTran I have updated the question

Comment: how do u load the image in the DetailActivity ?

Comment: @TinTran I use Picasso

Comment: Is the image url from the intent ?

Comment: I get from model class

Comment: @TinTran Check question with Picasso loading image from model

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145642/discussion-between-tin-tran-and-maharith-aditya-s-s).

Comment: It looks like this is happening when the `Fragment` in `TabActivity` is trying to save its state. Its state is 640KB which is too large. Can you post the relevant code from the `Fragment`? Also your layout files. This problem has nothing to do with "Serializable vs. Parcelable" and it has nothing to do with the `ProdModel` in the `Bundle`.

Comment: @DavidWasser I'll Update data you asked now. Please Let me know when you check it.

Comment: You've not posted enough code from the `Fragment`. The problem is not in `DetailActivity`, the problem is in the `Fragment` in `TabActivity`.

Comment: @DavidWasser Please Check Now

Comment: What is `private ArrayList<Root_SubCatModel> subCatList;`? You are calling `setArguments()` with a `Bundle` that contains this data for the `Fragment`. All data that you pass to `setArguments()` is saved automatically so that it persists across `Fragment` destruction and creation. I'm guessing that is where your problem is. Instead of doing this you could keep this data in the `Activity` and the `Fragment` could get the data from the `Activity` when it needs it.

Comment: @DavidWasser I'll Check and Let you Know

Comment: @DavidWasser I'm Sending Data coz it's a Viewpager fragment....so that data will be loaded based on catId of specific page

Comment: @DavidWasser Thanks a lot

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What to do on TransactionTooLargeException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11451393/what-to-do-on-transactiontoolargeexception)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your are passing too much data to your `Fragment` in `setArguments()`. Your `Fragment` will work, but when it tries to save its instance state it overflows the transaction buffer. This throws a `RuntimeException` **if you target Android 7.0 (API 24 or higher)**. To preserve backwards compatibility and not break existing apps, the new behaviour is only used if you target API 24 or higher. If you target API < 24, the transaction buffer overflow exception is caught and silently ignored. This means that your data will not be persistently saved, which you may (or may not) notice.

Your code is broken. You should not pass large amounts of data to the `Fragment` in `setArguments()`. You can keep your data in your `Activity`. When the `Fragment` wants to access the data, it can always so something like this:

```
// Get the owning Activity
MyActivity activity = (MyActivity)getActivity();
// Get the data from the Activity
List<Data> data = activity.getData();
```

In your `Activity`, write a `getData()` method that returns a reference to whatever data the `Fragment` needs.

In this way, the data is held in the `Activity` and the `Fragment` can get access to it whenever it needs to.

Comment: Thanks David. You save my time.

Comment: Instead cannot we directly access variables and methods using MyActivity.variable and MyActivity.anything() without MyActivity activity = (MyActivity)getActivity();?

Comment: @user1090751 You could only do that if the variables and methods were defined as `static`. This is possible, but violates basic principles of object-oriented design and is not generally recommended.

Comment: Beside violating the principles, how about performance issue?

Comment: @user1090751 The performance difference is near zero. You probably couldn't measure it and you certainly wouldn't notice it.

Answer (score 7):

Android 7.0 (Nogat) includes a variety of system and API behaviour changes.
Regarding TransactionTooLarge Exception :

> In Android 7.0, many platform APIs have now started checking for large
>   payloads being sent across Binder transactions, and the system now
>   rethrows TransactionTooLargeExceptions as RuntimeExceptions, instead
>   of silently logging or suppressing them. One common example is storing
>   too much data in Activity.onSaveInstanceState(), which causes
>   ActivityThread.StopInfo to throw a RuntimeException when your app
>   targets Android 7.0.

Possible Solutions :
 1. Save required object in global cache and pass only the key to DetailsActivity to retrieve the object.

Comment: I think your solution is not best practice. we should just save the object in some database/file and pass a key to the new Activity to retrieve it later.

Comment: Save it in DB/File only if you need it again, after app launch or app gets killed.
If its only required for showing details on click of some button, save it in memory, and clear it when app goes to background.

Comment: I am getting this exception -  android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 1100920 bytes
My code is about to insert the contact -
    ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

  ContentProviderResult[] res = context.getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);

How to solve it

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the Doc [This Exception](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/TransactionTooLargeException.html) throw  when value are too large to fit in the transaction buffer. And might be a complicated issue, for a big project, where you can invokes several actions with sending Intent in difference places.

Your example demonstrate this issue, even with single object. And you should change your transferring behavior at all. For ex. by trimming object, to contain only important info. **Intent Extra Data should have only lightweight info!**

---

In you example you have field, which might produce this issue. Probably you are using Base64 Encoded image. Exception with message text, specific only for Android 23. Check the doc.

```
public String getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(String image) {
    this.image = image;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Read this article http://nemanjakovacevic.net/blog/english/2015/03/24/yet-another-post-on-serializable-vs-parcelable/ should help you.

My solution:

1. Save your objects in some storage (SharedPreferences, raw JSON, SQLLite or Realm database etc.)
2. Put to your bundle only object 'id' (simple type: int long etc.)
3. Get 'id' from intent and find it in your storage, then retrieve the object.