# TransactionTooLargeException when Activity is Paused

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, exception, transactions

I am creating an application and in there I am sending very big data in `Bundle` from `Service` to the `Activity`. But I am not using `Messenger` for that. Instead, I am assigning data to a variable in singleton class and then I am retrieving data from that singleton class and assigning it to the activity.

In the `Activity`, I have a `ViewPager` in which two fragments are inflated. The `Bundle` is being sent to both of these `Fragment` classes.

Now, when the activity is paused, application is throwing following exception:

```
at android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run(ActivityThread.java:4209)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
                                                                     Caused by: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 4538408 bytes
                                                                        at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
                                                                        at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:628)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.activityStopped(ActivityManagerNative.java:4183)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run(ActivityThread.java:4201)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776) 
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520) 
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The bundle is being sent to both of these fragment classes.

Do not put large things into the saved instance state `Bundle`. In the case of fragments, the "arguments" `Bundle` (`setArguments()`) becomes part of the saved instance state `Bundle`, and so do not put large things into the arguments `Bundle`. The saved instance state `Bundle` is for tiny bits of data: as little as possible, but enough for you to restore your UI state after your process is terminated.

Instead, do something else, such as:

- Have the fragments call methods on the hosting activity to get this data, or
- Use a `ViewModel`, so that this data is retained across configuration changes but is not part of the saved instance state `Bundle`

Answer (score -2):

From [Android Developers - TransactionTooLargeException](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/TransactionTooLargeException.html)

> The Binder transaction buffer has a limited fixed size, currently 1Mb

And from similar question:
[What to do on TransactionTooLargeException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11451393/what-to-do-on-transactiontoolargeexception)

> Actually data size was around 500kb, and the IPC transaction buffer size is set to 1024KB.

So, data parcel size 4538408 bytes (4MB) is too large to send at once. Split it.