# Getting 'TransactionTooLargeException' after updating android studio 3.1

Tags: android, android-studio

I have develop android application in android studio 3.0 and it's working fine. When I updated android studio 3.0 to 3.1 after that my application not working and it's giving below error. When I am running application and touch on screen after that it's terminate my app. How to fix this error.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: Error reporting crash
                  android.os.TransactionTooLargeException
                      at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
                      at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:496)
                      at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.handleApplicationCrash(ActivityManagerNative.java:5016)
                      at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:95)
                      at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
                      at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 7480 SIG: 9
Application terminated.
```

Comment: refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11451393/what-to-do-on-transactiontoolargeexception?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Thanks Mohammed Ali for your response. I have tried given link by you but not solve my prob. I reinstalled my application but still its terminating my app when i touch on  login screen.

Comment: Moin can you provide more details, when you are getting this error?

Answer (score 1):

Finally found solution and here i am posting the answer below. There is a sum bug in android studio 3.1 profiling for edit text so I have disable the advance profiling.

Go to Run **-** Edit configurations **-** profiling **-** uncheck the enable advance profiling