# android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 3354884 bytes

Tags: android, transactiontoolargeexception

```
List<Data> data = fill_with_data();

public List<Data> fill_with_data() {
        List<Data> data = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < Glob.frames.length; i++) {
            data.add(new Data(Glob.frames[i]));
        }
        return data;
    }



public class Data {

    public int images;

    public Data(int images) {

        this.images = images;
    }
}
```

getting error while loading images from drawable folder
TransactionTooLargeException getting every time

Comment: What is `Glob`? You seems to writing heavy bytes . Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11451393/what-to-do-on-transactiontoolargeexception.

Comment: its global class which defines or use to pass common values

Comment: ii checked this link but i didn't get any solution for me

Comment: If You are writing those values to `Bundle`? You should look for other way around cause `Bundle` have limits on data size .

Comment: so what to do next in these i am tried to set images into recycleview and images came from drawable folder

Comment: Just pass the array of ids .

Comment: i passed only ids like R.drawable.frame1.....

Comment: Nope i did not have answer