# android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 565156 bytes

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have viewpager with fragmens, after so many scrolls app getting crashed by saying follwing , even their is no bundle exchange

while monitoring i found this following keys making the crash

```
 * android:support:fragments = 561.3 KB
    * android:fragments = 0.4 KB
    * com.google.firebase.analytics.screen_service = 0.2 KB
    * android:lastAutofillId = 0.1 KB
    * android:viewHierarchyState = 3.0 KB
```

these are all defalut, i am not assigning any bundle how can i fix this issue.

Comment: You can give a try to this in *Fragments* https://stackoverflow.com/a/32932631/3152529

Comment: it's already false inside fragment

Comment: Then read and try with different answer on same link if anything gets work.

Comment: thanks Jay, i got answer in same link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue can be fixed by clearing saved Bundle data like below

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle InstanceState) {
             super.onSaveInstanceState(InstanceState);
             InstanceState.clear();
}
```