# I get error "FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION" when I'm trying to save object in Firebase Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The problem is with setValue(loanedBooks). before adding this row it worked just fine.
I've marked the problematic row.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN){
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            //user logged in
            Log.d("AUTH",auth.getCurrentUser().getEmail());
            UserInfo user = auth.getCurrentUser();
            database.child("users").child(user.getUid()).child("name").setValue(user.getDisplayName());

            LoanedBooks loanedBooks = new LoanedBooks();
            **database.child("users").child(user.getUid()).child("loaned books").setValue(loanedBooks);** //this is the problem

            startActivity(intent_registered);

        }
        else{
            //user not authenticated
            Log.d("AUTH","NOT AUTHENTICATED");
        }
    }

}
```

LoanedBooks.java class:

```
public class LoanedBooks {
   public ArrayList<AddBook> loanedBooks_list;
   DatabaseReference database;

   public LoanedBooks(){
       loanedBooks_list = new ArrayList<AddBook>();
       database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();;
   }

   public ArrayList<AddBook> getLoanedBooksList(){
       return loanedBooks_list;
   }

   public void addBook(AddBook book){
       loanedBooks_list.add(book);
   }
}
```

error:

```
E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
E/AndroidRuntime: Error reporting crash
                  android.os.TransactionTooLargeException
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKvB6.png)

Comment: At which line of code are you getting this error?

Comment: It is not showing the line but when I remove this line it works:
database.child("users").child(user.getUid()).child("loaned books").setValue(loanedBooks)

Comment: It should indicate you the line at which occurs. Which is?

Comment: I've added a link to the error (below)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11451393/what-to-do-on-transactiontoolargeexception