# Should I clear bundle getExtra after getting the intent?

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to solve `TransactionTooLargeExeption` described in [What to do on TransactionTooLargeException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11451393/what-to-do-on-transactiontoolargeexception)

We are not using `onSaveInstanceState` in any siginificant way.

We are passing extra data when starting intent which is about 10-20k of data.

And app crashes after opening the activity about 30 times.

I'm speculating the extra data stacks up and crashes app, and thinking of doing `getIntent().removeExtra("data")` after I get the extra data in the receiving activity.

Is this usual to having to remove the received intent?

Comment: I would assume it means that you are somehow holding on to the intent or the data, which is not allowing it to be garbage collected.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [Source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/135936072b24b090fb63940aea41b408d855a4f3/core/java/android/content/Intent.java#4299) of `getExtras()` Method

```
public Bundle getExtras() {

   return (mExtras != null)
        ? new Bundle(mExtras)
        : null;
}
```

As you can see, Every time you call getExtras() it **creates a Copy** of your Data (in your case your data is too large )

So, i suggest you to remove your Extra after receiving it so you can free up your memory and avoid such an exception by using `removeExtra()` as you mentioned earlier.

Comment: This is nothing. It only makes a shallow copy, so very little extra memory used. Also, the copy will be released as soon as the piece of code finishes, and will not stay in memory.