# Extend transaction buffer limit for broadcast

Tags: android

I am trying to broadcast a Bitmap, but my Bitmap has a size larger than 1MB. When I broadcast that a TransactionTooLargeException is thrown. Storing the Bitmap and using the file path is not a valid option for me. Is there any way to extend this buffer limit?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What to do on TransactionTooLargeException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11451393/what-to-do-on-transactiontoolargeexception)

Comment: Convert the bitmap to byte[] and pass with intent?

Comment: @leonardkraemer I've seen this other problem, but because it's not possible to store my bitmap and I can not split this bitmap, I guess my question is not duplicated. I need to know if there is any way to extend the transaction limit.

Comment: @brandon I think converting the bitmap to a byte [] I'm going to face the same problem with size. I was thinking of splitting the byte [] into different chunks, but my service that will receive the chunks will not know how many chunks have been sent.

Comment: Just send the amount of chunks before you send them.

Comment: I am using an IntentService, so I will need to start that service for each chunk received, I do not know how to keep the context. Do you have any idea?