# Application terminated when you transfer using Intent putExtra Serializable

Tags: android, kotlin

I think this is due to the large data transfer to Intent. 
How can I transfer Serializable data to another Activity without restrictions ?

Start to produce an error only in partitions with a large amount of data.

```py
val stocksActivityIntent = Intent(context, StocksActivity::class.java)

stocksActivityIntent.putExtra("PARTNER_KEY", partners[position])
stocksActivityIntent.putExtra("CATEGORY_KEY", "StocksCategoty")

context.startActivity(stocksActivityIntent)
```

Comment: Try check the logcat and post it to the question

Comment: 2019-08-22 13:30:20.412 1964-2285/system_process E/ActivityManager: Transaction too large, intent: Intent { cmp=ru757571.discount/.controllers.stocks.StocksActivity (has extras) }, extras size: 541596, icicle size: 0
2019-08-22 13:30:20.417 1964-2285/system_process E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 545232)

Comment: It says `Transaction too large`, `extras size: 541596`. which means that your serialized class is too large to be passed through intent. I was unable to find documented limit, but tests show it is about 504 KB

Comment: I'm new to kotlin. How can I transfer data in another way ?

Comment: what is that large in your class?

Comment: I am passing a json that is downloaded from the site

Comment: you have to pass it some other way. For example save it to the file in one activity, and load in another

Comment: the limit is 1Mb and on api 27 and above i believe it will actually cause a crash

Comment: the 1mb does not necessarily have to be just the data u passed btw, it will include all kinds of stuff like states, other system data etc and the bundle limit is for across all your application classes

Comment: @Kushan how can I bypass this limit and transfer data ?

Comment: @Vladyslav Matviienko It seems to me that writing to the file will be too slow, maybe there is a faster solution ?

Comment: you can use some static field for example.

Comment: @Vladyslav Matviienko You can give a small example. I do so where you need to get var partner: Partner? = null. val activity = StocksActivity()
                activity.partner= partners[position]

                val stocksActivityIntent = Intent(context, activity::class.java)
                stocksActivityIntent.putExtra("CATEGORY_KEY", "StocksCategoty")

                context.startActivity(stocksActivityIntent)

Comment: `StocksActivity()` never create an instance of Activity.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11451393/what-to-do-on-transactiontoolargeexception)

Comment: You can try use this library: https://github.com/livefront/bridge or store data inside Singleton and retrieving that data inside other activity

Answer (score 0):

StocksActivity.kt

```
companion object {
    var partner: Partner? = null
}
```

StocksCategory.kt

```
val stocksActivityIntent = Intent(context, StocksActivity::class.java)

StocksActivity.partner = partners[position]
stocksActivityIntent.putExtra("CATEGORY_KEY", "StocksCategoty")

context.startActivity(stocksActivityIntent)
```

@Vladyslav Matviienko, Thanks for your help )

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();         
bundle.putSerializable("newItem", item); 
intent.putExtras(bundle);
```

In Activity class include

```
Intent intent = this.getIntent(); 
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
item= (Item)bundle.getSerializable("newItem");
```

Comment: Is there an example on kotlin ?

Comment: this won't help, as serialized `item` size is over extras limit