# Caused by android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 5971992 bytes is there any tool to debug this error

Tags: android, kotlin, transactiontoolargeexception

I am working on the production app. I am receiving the exception in Crashlytics. I don't have a clue where is happening because it is not pointing any activity. Just I am getting an error like this.

```
Caused by android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 5971992 bytes
   at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(BinderProxy.java)
   at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(BinderProxy.java:1179)
   at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.activityStopped(IActivityManager.java:3969)
   at android.app.servertransaction.PendingTransactionActions$StopInfo.run(PendingTransactionActions.java:144)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6898)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:537)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Is there any tool/library to detect this issue

I checked this link also [What to do on TransactionTooLargeException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11451393/what-to-do-on-transactiontoolargeexception)

I tried this tool https://github.com/guardian/toolargetoo it's not helpful for me.Can you kindly share your ideas

Comment: are you passing large set of data via intent to another activity? can you check that. very difficult to tell whats happening without more details.

Comment: No bro I am not passing large data like POJO. Just passing key-value pairs

Comment: you need to debug yourself. the details provided here are not enough for anyone to assume whats happening.

Comment: Yes even while testing in staging mode I am not getting errors in the application, In production, I am receiving this bug even which screen not able to find bro

Comment: In addition to Intents, have a look at your activities and fragments if they'd be storing potentially large data in an instance state parcel.

Comment: Agreed on the instance state -- from this particular stack trace, that seems like the most likely culprit. So, for example, do not put a `Bitmap` into the saved instance state `Bundle`.

Comment: Thank you all I will try to debug all places

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks man I got my answer from your comment. It was due to putting parceable  bitmap  into the saved instance state Bundle .

Answer (score 0):

Caused by android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 5971992 bytes is there any tool to debug this error

Store the Data into the SharedPreferences Like This

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
                            editor.putString("HipId",services.get(position).getId());
                            editor.putString("PatientId",services.get(position).getPatient_id());
                         editor.putString("DataPush",services.get(position).getData_push());
editor.apply();// this Kb Data
Intent intent = new Intent(context, SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);

and fetch the Data SecondActivity class

     hipId=sharedpreferences.getString("HipId", "");;
      PatientId=sharedpreferences.getString("PatientId", "");
     String data=sharedpreferences.getString("DataPush", "");
```