# Is there any way to find exact line of TransactionToolargExcetion,

Tags: android, transactiontoolargeexception

I am facing the transaction too large exception is there a way to find the exact line, like normal errors, will show null pointer exception. This issue is happening longer time

I checked this thread also I dint get what I'm expecting

[What to do on TransactionTooLargeException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11451393/what-to-do-on-transactiontoolargeexception)

Comment: There are specific reasons for `TransactionTooLargeException` .. Have read [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11451393/what-to-do-on-transactiontoolargeexception)..

Comment: "is there a way to find the exact line" -- not usually.