# Which is the better way to share data between Fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-architecture-components, android-viewmodel, android-safe-args

I want to share a few Integer values from one fragment to the other. I don't want lose the data when the device changes configuration.

So the two ways that I came across and want to know which one will be better for my use case are:

#### 1. Sharing a `ViewModel` among multiple fragments

```
class SharedViewModel : ViewModel(){
    ...
}

class FragmentA : Fragment(){
    private val model: SharedViewModel by activityViewModels()
    ...
}

class FragmentB : Fragment(){
    private val model: SharedViewModel by activityViewModels()
    ...
}
```

#### 2. Using combination of SafeArgs and custom `ViewModelProvider.Factory`

Using SafeArgs to pass data as a parameter to a navigation action from a fragment (say A) to another fragmet (say B). Implementing `ViewModel` (parameterized) and `ViewModelFactory` classes for fragment B. Passing the data from SafeArgs to ViewModelFactory to create a ViewModel (using `ViewModelProvider`)

Something like this:

```
class B : Fragment() {

    //Seperate classes for ViewModelB & ViewModelFactoryB
    private lateinit var viewModel: ViewModelB
    private lateinit var viewModelFactory: ViewModelFactoryB

    override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater,
            container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        val binding: BFragmentBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
                inflater,
                R.layout.b_fragment,
                container,
                false
        )

        viewModelFactory = ViewModelFactoryB(BFragmentArgs.fromBundle(requireArguments()).data)
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, viewModelFactoryB).get(ViewModelB::class.java)

        return binding.root
    }
}
```

Comment: When you ask for the best but you don't mention in which circumstances, each upcoming answer may be biased based on how everyone sees it. but I think it is a good start for you to see this page.

https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data

Comment: I hope my question clearly explains my use case now. Sorry for not framing it properly earlier.

Comment: Bundles and intents are not working for me so the ViewModelProvider is the better option: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70135731/passing-data-through-navigation-between-fragments-android-studio/78214917#78214917.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It totally depends on your use case, what data you share between fragments and how it is used.

Even though both cases support passing custom objects you have to consider a few things.

In the case of the navigation component, **regarding custom objects**:

- data must be either Parcelable (preferred) or Serializable;
- all of the data passed through using `Bundle` object which has its own limitations and with large data can lead to `TransactionTooLargeException` ([more about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11451393/what-to-do-on-transactiontoolargeexception)). It can be easily avoided when using shared view model.

In the case of shared view models:

- you have to define new classes to wrap your models;
- you have to add new class members to hold shared view models;
- a shared view model will take memory until Activity is finished or the view model store is cleared.

#### So what is the answer?

Such a question leads to opinionated answers, but I consider following a set of hints to use when choosing between [safe argument](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data#Safe-args) and [shared view model](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing).

Use safe arguments when:

1. data is small;
2. when you **do not** need to return results to the previous fragment after using this data;
3. you do not care if this data is removed from memory when you are done with it and you have to query it again each time.

Use a shared view model when:

1. data is relatively large or you assume it could be large;
2. you have multiple data models/sets;
3. when you **do** need to return results to the previous fragment after using this data;
4. when data is expensive to query. Shared view models typically live as long as the activity.

Comment: Sorry for not framing the question properly. I wanted to know how to choose between the two ways and your answer explains just that. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: I want to share a few integer values from `FragmentA` to `FragmentB`, so the data which I'm sharing is small. For using **SafeArgs** I'd have to create a `ViewModelFactory` and a `ViewModel` separately for FragmentB and pass the integers from Bundle to ViewModel factory. Although I will avoid all this code if I share a ViewModel between those fragments. What would you suggest me to proceed with?

Comment: For safe arguments, you do not need any ViewModel related classes. You need to use the navigation component and in your navigation graph you should define two arguments. [Example of one argument](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data#override_a_destination_argument_in_an_action). Then in your receiver fragment you can use `MyFragmentArgs.fromBundle(getArguments()).get[variable_name_here]();` to get value passed in.

Comment: In order to take care of Configuration changes in my app I'd either have to use `onSaveInstanceState()` or **ViewModel** but since I'm currently learning Architecture Components I'd want to use ViewModel. In that case, I have two ways (that I know) to achieve this as mentioned in the question.

Comment: Then use view models. It will be easier to use [shared view model](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing). There is a small piece of code in that topic by the link. It is all you need to set and access data from one fragment to the other.