# Webview Activity crash due to TransactionTooLarge error

Tags: android, kotlin, webview, crash, transactiontoolargeexception

I using webview to render a form. Application get crash after `onPageStarted` method and in LogCat I am finding below error.

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 603696 bytes
        at android.app.servertransaction.PendingTransactionActions$StopInfo.run(PendingTransactionActions.java:160)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 603696 bytes
        at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
        at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:1127)
        at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.activityStopped(IActivityManager.java:4027)
        at android.app.servertransaction.PendingTransactionActions$StopInfo.run(PendingTransactionActions.java:144)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

I am not saving anything in OnSavedInstanceState().

Comment: I guess this might help you understand the error https://stackoverflow.com/a/12809171/3159267

Comment: Hello @rajan.kali thanks for you help but I am not calling any API I am just loading one URL in webview.

In webview OnPagetstart called and after that I am getting this error

Comment: have you tried to debug with `ADB`? https://link.medium.com/8rNw2UvIXhb. You might wanna check the activity before opening `WebView` (if there's any `onSaveInstanceState` called before opening the `WebView` that made the `WebView#onPageStart` failed or crashed

Answer (score 0):

add

```
webView.getSettings().domStorageEnabled = true
```

before load url and after load url add these two line it will works.

```
webView.webChromeClient = WebChromeClient()
webView.webViewClient = WebViewClient()
```

Answer (score 0):

the WebView itself might be saving a large state which exceeds the Binder transaction buffer limit.

```
override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
    outState.putParcelable("android:webViewState", null)
}
```

this replace the WebView state with a null value, ensuring that it doesn't get saved.