# Is there any way to stop TransactionTooLargeException error in Android?

Tags: android

I am getting a `TransactionTooLargeException` error in my app

I have an `EditText` in my app and I have pasted more than 1207324 bytes of text here

Up to this point, no error occurs, but `TransactionTooLargeException` occurs when moving to another activity.

It doesn't pass any data to other activities, it just opens a new activity.

How can I resolve `TransactionTooLargeException`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What to do on TransactionTooLargeException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11451393/what-to-do-on-transactiontoolargeexception)

Comment: `It doesn't pass any data to other activities,` You are not saving that text in onSaveInstanceState() ? Does it happen at rotating the device too?

Comment: @blackapps: "You are not saving that text in onSaveInstanceState() ?" -- text in an `EditText` is automatically placed in the saved instance state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Validate your form. If the user has entered too much text (e.g., 100KB), warn them and force them to make changes before you proceed to the next activity.