# onSavedInstanceState TransactionTooLargeException (only on lock screen or start activity not on rotate screen)

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, transactiontoolargeexception

I'm facing an issue on the Activity Lifecycle when `onSavedInstanceState` is Called.

Let me explain :
I have **4 `Fragments` on `ViewPager`** hosting `RecyclerViews`.
These `RecyclerViews` display data from `HashMap<String, AMedia>()`.

The HashMap can be large, when I rotate the phone (portrait/landscape) the `onSavedInstanceState` and on `onViewStateRestored` are called and data are well transmitted by the Framework on the UI like following :

```
@Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putSerializable("medias", mMapMedias);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public void onViewStateRestored(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState);
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mMapMedias = (HashMap<String, ArrayList<AMedia>>) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("medias");
            render();
        }
    }
```

But when I **lock** or `start an other activity` the phone only `onSaveInstanceState` and app begins crash on the lock screen with error :

```
JNI critical lock held for 29.211ms on Thread[1,tid=27712,Runnable,Thread*=0xb400007388322010,peer=0x73356338,"main"]
JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 45037652)
W/ActivityStopInfo: Bundle stats:
ActivityStopInfo:   android:viewHierarchyState [size=1036]
JNI critical lock held for 128.524ms on Thread[1,tid=27712,Runnable,Thread*=0xb400007388322010,peer=0x73356338,"main"]
ActivityStopInfo:   androidx.lifecycle.BundlableSavedStateRegistry.key [size=45035172]
ActivityStopInfo:     android:support:activity-result [size=2908]
ActivityStopInfo:       KEY_COMPONENT_ACTIVITY_REGISTERED_KEYS [size=2192]
JNI critical lock held for 88.565ms on Thread[1,tid=27712,Runnable,Thread*=0xb400007388322010,peer=0x73356338,"main"]
ActivityStopInfo:     android:support:fragments [size=45032008]
JNI critical lock held for 86.960ms on Thread[1,tid=27712,Runnable,Thread*=0xb400007388322010,peer=0x73356338,"main"]
ActivityStopInfo:       android:support:fragments [size=45031936]
ActivityStopInfo: PersistableBundle stats:
W/ActivityStopInfo:   [null]
AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
    
    --------- beginning of crash
AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    PID: 27712
    java.lang.RuntimeException: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 45037652 bytes
        at android.app.servertransaction.PendingTransactionActions$StopInfo.run(PendingTransactionActions.java:161)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:233)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8010)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:631)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:978)
     Caused by: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 45037652 bytes
        at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
        at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(BinderProxy.java:591)
        at android.app.IActivityTaskManager$Stub$Proxy.activityStopped(IActivityTaskManager.java:4408)
        at android.app.servertransaction.PendingTransactionActions$StopInfo.run(PendingTransactionActions.java:145)
```

I think on rotate the same calls are done through JavaBinder but not crashing, why on Lock or start an other activity it crashs ?

Any solution ? I'm testing on Android 12.

Comment: I've left a comment on a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73008611/2860701