# What is "androidx.lifecycle.BundlableSavedStateRegistry.key" in this bundle?

Tags: android, kotlin, androidx, android-bundle, onsaveinstancestate

I'm using `toolargetool` to investigate why the app is crashing from `TransactionTooLargeException`.

I'm seeing there's this key `androidx.lifecycle.BundlableSavedStateRegistry.key` which can be around 400 KB when I put the app into the background.

What is this key and where is it coming from? How can I reduce the size of this in the bundle?

Comment: That key is itself a `Bundle`. What inside _that_ Bundle is actually taking up space?

Comment: After some investigation, I think the key is relating to some values stored via `SavedStateHandle` in the view model. I found out some huge data being passed through there. Not sure why `TooLargeTool` doesn't give me the key values defined in the VM and passed through `SavedStateHandle` instead of giving me `androidx.lifecycle.BundlableSavedStateRegistry.key`. I could be wrong on this assumption though.

Comment: I've answered a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73008611/2860701

Comment: i have the same question:
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76548713/about-activity-onsaveinstancestate-toolarge-the-question-cause-by-androidx-lif)

Answer (score 7):

In my case, here are the things that was stored there:

- androidx:appcompat = 0.1 KB
- android:support:lifecycle = 0.1 KB
- androidx.lifecycle.internal.SavedStateHandlesProvider = 1.2 KB
- android:support:activity-result = 28.3 KB
- android:support:fragments = 644.2 KB

I recommend you to debug this yourself because stored things and their sizes will be different for your project.

To debug:

1. Put a breakpoint in `TooLargeTool.bundleBreakdown()` function. In the breakpoint, you can also use a filter like: `KB(totalSize) > 500` so that it will stop at breakpoint only for the large sized Bundles such as Bundles that are larger than 500 KB.

[image: breakpoint popup of TooLargeTool]

2. Once it hits the breakpoint you can "evaluate expression" in the IDE.

In the breakpoint try evaluating code like this:

```
val bundle: Bundle = bundle.getBundle("androidx.lifecycle.BundlableSavedStateRegistry.key")!!
// bundleBreakdown(bundle) // <- this gives you a report including size etc.
val fragmentsBundle = bundle.getBundle("android:support:fragments")!!
bundleBreakdown(fragmentsBundle)
```

You can of course also see the bundles in the IDE's Debug window, but it will be difficult to see the Bundle keys and sizes.

This way you can find out exactly what takes up space in this Bundle with key `androidx.lifecycle.BundlableSavedStateRegistry.key`