# about Activity.onSaveInstanceState toolarge the question cause by : androidx.lifecycle.BundlableSavedStateRegistry.key = 795.1 KB

Tags: android, transactiontoolargeexception

I have Bussiness Activity ：created 3 vm  by：

```
 private val vm by viewModels<DetailVM>()
 private val envCheckVM by viewModels<EnvCheckVM>()

and xml：
have four FragmentContainerView:

<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
 android:id="@+id/fcv_order_top_state"
 android:name="com.dofun.zhw.lite.ui.order.InfoStateFragment1"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/dp13" />

<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
 android:id="@+id/fcv_order_top_state"
 android:name="com.dofun.zhw.lite.ui.order.InfoStateFragment2"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/dp13" />

<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
 android:id="@+id/fcv_order_top_state"
 android:name="com.dofun.zhw.lite.ui.order.InfoStateFragment3"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/dp13" />

<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
 android:id="@+id/fcv_order_top_state"
 android:name="com.dofun.zhw.lite.ui.order.InfoStateFragment4"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/dp13" />

every fragment use activity viewmodel by:

private val vm by activityViewModels<DetailVM>()
private val complaintLimitVM by viewModels<OrderComplaintLimitVM>()
```

online exception:  TransactionTooLargeException cause by:
androidx.lifecycle.BundlableSavedStateRegistry.key = 795.1 KB

only by this activity，get help? thinks~

online exception:  TransactionTooLargeException cause by:
androidx.lifecycle.BundlableSavedStateRegistry.key = 795.1 KB

only by this activity，get help? thinks~

Comment: What does [TooLargeTool](https://github.com/guardian/toolargetool) say is taking up too much space?

Comment: troubleshoot online errors by toolargetool，cause by TransactionTooLargeException