# how to tackle TransactionTooLargeException in Android applications?

Tags: java, android, android-room, datastore, transactiontoolargeexception

one of our Android application is crashing sometimes with TransactionTooLargeException as we are putting an ArrayList of approx size 500 (Shallow Size of 85,000 / Retained size of 1,400,000). I understand that we need to use **DataStore** or **Room DB** instead of `intent.putExtras(bundle)`. Any suggestion on which method is ideal for this type of scenario?  and if you can point me to a good resource on how to implement it in SDK 33?

```
Transaction too large, intent: Intent { cmp=client.*****/.********* (has extras) }, extras size: 603940, icicle size: 0
14:19:54.677  E  Second failure launching client.*****/.********, giving up
                 android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 606852 bytes
                    at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
                    at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(BinderProxy.java:653)
                    at android.app.IApplicationThread$Stub$Proxy.scheduleTransaction(IApplicationThread.java:2031)
                    at android.app.servertransaction.ClientTransaction.schedule(ClientTransaction.java:136)
                    at com.android.server.wm.ClientLifecycleManager.scheduleTransaction(ClientLifecycleManager.java:47)
                    at com.android.server.wm.ActivityTaskSupervisor.realStartActivityLocked(ActivityTaskSupervisor.java:1063)
                    at com.android.server.wm.RootWindowContainer$AttachApplicationHelper.test(RootWindowContainer.java:4219)
                    at com.android.server.wm.RootWindowContainer$AttachApplicationHelper.test(RootWindowContainer.java:4169)
                    at com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.forAllActivities(ActivityRecord.java:5362)
                    at com.android.server.wm.WindowContainer.forAllActivities(WindowContainer.java:1712)
                    at com.android.server.wm.WindowContainer.forAllActivities(WindowContainer.java:1706)
                    at com.android.server.wm.RootWindowContainer$AttachApplicationHelper.accept(RootWindowContainer.java:4207)
                    at com.android.server.wm.RootWindowContainer$AttachApplicationHelper.accept(RootWindowContainer.java:4169)
                    at com.android.server.wm.Task.forAllRootTasks(Task.java:4033)
                    at com.android.server.wm.WindowContainer.forAllRootTasks(WindowContainer.java:2088)
                    at com.android.server.wm.WindowContainer.forAllRootTasks(WindowContainer.java:2088)
                    at com.android.server.wm.WindowContainer.forAllRootTasks(WindowContainer.java:2088)
                    at com.android.server.wm.WindowContainer.forAllRootTasks(WindowContainer.java:2088)
                    at com.android.server.wm.WindowContainer.forAllRootTasks(WindowContainer.java:2088)
                    at com.android.server.wm.WindowContainer.forAllRootTasks(WindowContainer.java:2088)
                    at com.android.server.wm.WindowContainer.forAllRootTasks(WindowContainer.java:2081)
                    at com.android.server.wm.RootWindowContainer$AttachApplicationHelper.process(RootWindowContainer.java:4185)
                    at com.android.server.wm.RootWindowContainer.attachApplication(RootWindowContainer.java:2203)
                    at com.android.server.wm.ActivityTaskManagerService$LocalService.attachApplication(ActivityTaskManagerService.java:7573)
                    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.attachApplicationLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:5782)
                    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.attachApplication(ActivityManagerService.java:5890)
                    at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub.onTransact(IActivityManager.java:2764)
                    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:3077)
                    at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1316)
                    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1280)
```

Comment: What are you using the list for on the other side?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What to do on TransactionTooLargeException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11451393/what-to-do-on-transactiontoolargeexception)