# RuntimeException android.os.TransactionTooLargeException

Tags: android, kotlin, android-navhostfragment

I have a crash in my app that I don't know how to fix. Here is the stack trace:

```
RuntimeException
android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 527140 bytes

android.app.ActivityClient in activityStopped at line 88
System
android.app.servertransaction.PendingTransactionActions$StopInfo in run at line 143
System
android.os.Handler in handleCallback at line 942
System
android.os.Handler in dispatchMessage at line 99
System
android.os.Looper in loopOnce at line 226
System
android.os.Looper in loop at line 313
System
android.app.ActivityThread in main at line 8757
System
java.lang.reflect.Method in invoke
System
com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller in run at line 571
System
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit in main at line 1067
System
TransactionTooLargeException
data parcel size 527140 bytes

android.os.BinderProxy in transactNative
System
android.os.BinderProxy in transact at line 662
System
android.app.IActivityClientController$Stub$Proxy in activityStopped at line 1309
System
android.app.ActivityClient in activityStopped at line 85
System
android.app.servertransaction.PendingTransactionActions$StopInfo in run at line 143
System
android.os.Handler in handleCallback at line 942
System
android.os.Handler in dispatchMessage at line 99
System
android.os.Looper in loopOnce at line 226
System
android.os.Looper in loop at line 313
System
android.app.ActivityThread in main at line 8757
System
java.lang.reflect.Method in invoke
System
com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller in run at line 571
System
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit in main at line 1067
```

This started happening when I transformed our app into a tab bar app using a nav host fragment using mobile_navigation.xml.

Here is the xml for the main activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/black_bottom_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/tab_bar_height"
            android:background="@color/black"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Group
            android:id="@+id/tab_bar_group"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:constraint_referenced_ids="black_bottom_view,nav_view" />

        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:itemIconSize="80dp"
            app:itemIconTint="@color/nav_menu_item_color"
            app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/black_bottom_view"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Here is the mobile_navigation.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@+id/navigation_home">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
        android:name="com.mApp.home.HomeFragment"
        android:label="@string/tab_bar_label_home"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_navigation_home_to_navigation_c"
            app:destination="@id/navigation_c"
              />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_navigation_home_to_navigation_v_i"
            app:destination="@id/navigation_v_i"
              />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_navigation_home_to_navigation_view_profile"
            app:destination="@id/navigation_view_profile"
              />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_navigation_home_to_navigation_preferences"
            app:destination="@id/navigation_preferences"

            />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_navigation_home_to_navigation_personal_info"
            app:destination="@id/navigation_personal_info"
              />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_navigation_home_to_navigation_i_m"
            app:destination="@id/navigation_i_m"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/bottom_to_top"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/stay"
            app:popEnterAnim="@anim/bottom_to_top"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/stay" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_navigation_home_to_navigation_media_preview"
            app:destination="@id/navigation_media_preview"
             />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_navigation_home_to_navigation_notifications"
            app:destination="@id/navigation_notifications"
              />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_swlm"
        android:name="com.mApp.swlm.SWLMFragment">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_navigation_swlm_to_navigation_mup_settings"
            app:destination="@id/navigation_mup_settings"
              />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_navigation_swlm_to_navigation_personal_info"
            app:destination="@id/navigation_personal_info"
              />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_c"
        android:name="com.mApp.c.cList.CListFragment">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_navigation_c_list_to_navigation_single_c"
            app:destination="@id/navigation_single_c"

            />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_navigation_c_list_to_navigation_swlm"
            app:destination="@id/navigation_swlm"
            />
        <argument
            android:name="mProfile"
            app:argType="com.mApp.dataobjects.MProfile"
            app:nullable="true"
            android:defaultValue="@null" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_navigation_c_list_to_navigation_archive"
            app:destination="@id/navigation_archive"

            />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_navigation_c_list_to_navigation_home"
            app:destination="@id/navigation_home"
            
            />
        <argument
            android:name="isNewM"
            app:argType="boolean"
            android:defaultValue="false" />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_archive"
        android:name="com.mApp.c.archive.ArchiveFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_archive" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_navigation_archive_to_navigation_single_c"
            app:destination="@id/navigation_single_c"

            />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_single_c"
        android:name="com.mApp.c.CFragment"
        >
        <argument
            android:name="mProfile"
            app:argType="com.mApp.dataobjects.MProfile" />
        <argument
            android:name="callId"
            app:argType="long"
            android:defaultValue="0L" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_navigation_single_c_to_navigation_d"
            app:destination="@id/navigation_d"
             />
        <argument
            android:name="shouldShowTabBarOnBack"
            app:argType="boolean"
            android:defaultValue="true" />
        <argument
            android:name="isFromArchiveScreen"
            app:argType="boolean"
            android:defaultValue="false" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_navigation_single_c_to_navigation_view_profile"
            app:destination="@id/navigation_view_profile"
              />
        <argument
            android:name="isNewM"
            app:argType="boolean"
            android:defaultValue="false" />
        <argument
            android:name="isFromIM"
            app:argType="boolean"
            android:defaultValue="false" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_navigation_single_c_to_navigation_d_full_detail"
            app:destination="@id/navigation_d_full_detail"
              />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_d"
        android:name="com.mApp.d.dssdk.experiences.browse.main.DMainFragment">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_navigation_d_to_navigation_d_category"
            app:destination="@id/navigation_d_category"
            
            />
        <argument
            android:name="mUserId"
            app:argType="string"
            app:nullable="true"
            android:defaultValue="@null" />
        <argument
            android:name="mId"
            app:argType="string"
            app:nullable="true"
            android:defaultValue="@null" />
        <argument
            android:name="mName"
            app:argType="string"
            app:nullable="true"
            android:defaultValue="@null" />
        <argument
            android:name="mPhotoUrl"
            app:argType="string"
            app:nullable="true"
            android:defaultValue="@null" />
        <argument
            android:name="mProfile"
            app:argType="com.mApp.dataobjects.MProfile"
            app:nullable="true"
            android:defaultValue="@null" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_navigation_d_to_navigation_d_filtered"
            app:destination="@id/navigation_d_filtered"
            
            />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_navigation_d_to_navigation_c"
            app:destination="@id/navigation_chat"
            
            />
        <argument
            android:name="categoryId"
            app:argType="string"
            app:nullable="true"
            android:defaultValue="@null"
            />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_navigation_d_to_navigation_d_full_detail"
            app:destination="@id/navigation_d_full_detail"
              />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_media_preview"
        android:name="com.mApp.mediaPreview.MediaPreviewFragment"
        android:label="Media Preview">
        <argument
            android:name="url"
            app:argType="string" />
        <argument
            android:name="isIMedia"
            app:argType="boolean" />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_account"
        android:name="com.mApp.account.AccountFragment"
        >
        <argument
            android:name="settingsAction"
            android:defaultValue="NONE"
            app:argType="com.mApp.account.SettingsAction" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_navigation_main_menu_to_navigation_preferences"
            app:destination="@id/navigation_preferences"

            />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_navigation_main_menu_to_navigation_settings"
            app:destination="@id/navigation_settings"

            />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_navigation_main_menu_to_navigation_mup_settings"
            app:destination="@id/navigation_mup_settings"
              />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_navigation_main_menu_to_navigation_v_i"
            app:destination="@id/navigation_v_i"
              />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_navigation_account_to_navigation_view_profile"
            app:destination="@id/navigation_view_profile"
              />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_navigation_account_to_navigation_debug_menu"
            app:destination="@id/navigation_debug_menu"
              />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_settings"
        android:name="com.mApp.settings.SettingsFragment"
        android:label="@string/settings.settings_title"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_settings" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_navigation_account_to_navigation_preferences"
            app:destination="@id/navigation_preferences"
            
            />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_navigation_account_to_navigation_notification_settings"
            app:destination="@id/navigation_notification_settings"
              />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_navigation_account_to_navigation_mup_settings"
            app:destination="@id/navigation_mup_settings"
              />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_notification_settings"
        android:name="com.mApp.notificationSettings.NotificationSettingsFragment"
        android:label="@string/tab_bar_label_notification_settings">
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_mup_settings"
        android:name="com.mApp.mupSettings.MUPSettingsFragment">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_navigation_mup_settings_to_navigation_swlm"
            app:destination="@id/navigation_swlm"
             />
        <argument
            android:name="showNPaywall"
            app:argType="boolean"
            android:defaultValue="false" />
        <argument
            android:name="showBPaywall"
            app:argType="boolean"
            android:defaultValue="false" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_navigation_mup_settings_to_navigation_w"
            app:destination="@id/navigation_w"
              />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_navigation_mup_settings_to_navigation_promo_events"
            app:destination="@id/navigation_promo_events"
              />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_navigation_mup_settings_to_navigation_preferences"
            app:destination="@id/navigation_preferences"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/screen_pop_enter"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/screen_pop_exit"
            app:popEnterAnim="@anim/screen_pop_enter"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/screen_pop_exit" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_navigation_mup_settings_to_navigation_settings"
            app:destination="@id/navigation_settings"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/screen_pop_enter"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/screen_pop_exit"
            app:popEnterAnim="@anim/screen_pop_enter"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/screen_pop_exit" />
        <argument
            android:name="openPromoCode"
            app:argType="boolean"
            android:defaultValue="false" />
        <argument
            android:name="promoCode"
            app:argType="string"
            app:nullable="true"
            android:defaultValue="@null" />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_edit_profile_home"
        android:name="com.mApp.editVersion3.home.EditProfileHomeFragment"
        android:label="Edit Profile Home">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_navigation_edit_profile_home_to_navigation_a_y"
            app:destination="@id/navigation_a_y"
              />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_navigation_edit_profile_home_to_navigation_interests"
            app:destination="@id/navigation_interests"
              />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_navigation_edit_profile_home_to_navigation_personal_info"
            app:destination="@id/navigation_personal_info"
             />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_navigation_edit_profile_home_to_navigation_upload_photo"
            app:destination="@id/navigation_upload_photo"
              />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_navigation_edit_profile_home_to_navigation_v_i"
            app:destination="@id/navigation_v_i"
              />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_navigation_edit_profile_home_to_navigation_view_profile"
            app:destination="@id/navigation_view_profile"
              />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_personal_info"
        android:name="com.mApp.editVersion3.personalInformation.PersonalInfoFragment"
        android:label="Personal Info"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_personal_info" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_navigation_personal_info_to_navigation_view_profile"
            app:destination="@id/navigation_view_profile"
             />
        <argument
            android:name="shouldShowTabBarOnClose"
            app:argType="boolean"
            android:defaultValue="false" />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_d_account"
        android:name="com.mApp.d.dssdk.experiences.purchased.account.ExperienceAccountFragment"
        >
        <argument
            android:name="dPurchased"
            app:argType="boolean"
            android:defaultValue="false" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_navigation_d_account_to_navigation_d_settings"
            app:destination="@id/navigation_d_settings"
              />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_navigation_d_account_to_navigation_d_notifications"
            app:destination="@id/navigation_d_notifications"
              />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_navigation_d_account_to_navigation_d_full_detail"
            app:destination="@id/navigation_d_full_detail"
              />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_crop_image"
        android:name="com.mApp.edit.photo.CropImageFragment"
        android:label="Crop Image"
        tools:layout="@layout/activity_crop_image" >
        <argument
            android:name="source"
            app:argType="string" />
        <argument
            android:name="photoId"
            app:argType="string" />
        <argument
            android:name="isFromImagesGrid"
            app:argType="boolean"
            android:defaultValue="false" />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_upload_photo"
        android:name="com.mApp.editVersion3.uploadPhoto.UploadPhotoFragment"
        android:label="Upload Photo"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_photo_upload" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_navigation_upload_photo_to_navigation_crop_image"
            app:destination="@id/navigation_crop_image"
              />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_navigation_upload_photo_to_navigation_album_list"
            app:destination="@id/navigation_album_list"

            />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_navigation_upload_photo_to_navigation_images_grid"
            app:destination="@id/navigation_images_grid"

            />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_album_list"
        android:name="com.mApp.edit.photo.AlbumListFragment"
        android:label="Album List"
        tools:layout="@layout/activity_album_list" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_navigation_album_list_to_navigation_images_grid"
            app:destination="@id/navigation_images_grid"
              />
        <argument
            android:name="isPromptPhoto"
            app:argType="boolean" />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_images_grid"
        android:name="com.mApp.edit.photo.ImagesGridFragment"
        android:label="Images Grid"
        tools:layout="@layout/activity_images_grid" >
        <argument
            android:name="source"
            app:argType="string" />
        <argument
            android:name="albumId"
            app:argType="long" />
        <argument
            android:name="isPromptPhoto"
            app:argType="boolean" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_navigation_images_grid_to_navigation_crop_image"
            app:destination="@id/navigation_crop_image"
              />
        <argument
            android:name="isFromAlbumList"
            app:argType="boolean"
            android:defaultValue="false" />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_a_y"
        android:name="com.mApp.editVersion3.aY.AYFragment"
        >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_navigation_a_y_to_navigation_images_grid"
            app:destination="@id/navigation_images_grid"

            />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_navigation_a_y_to_navigation_album_list"
            app:destination="@id/navigation_album_list"

            />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_i_m"
        android:name="com.mApp.im.IMFragment"
        >
        <argument
            android:name="isATeaser"
            app:argType="boolean"
            android:defaultValue="false" />
        <argument
            android:name="mComment"
            app:argType="com.mApp.dataobjects.Comment"
            app:nullable="true"
            android:defaultValue="@null" />
        <argument
            android:name="tComment"
            app:argType="com.mApp.dataobjects.Comment"
            app:nullable="true"
            android:defaultValue="@null" />
        <argument
            android:name="mProfile"
            app:argType="com.mApp.dataobjects.MProfile" />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_interests"
        android:name="com.mApp.editVersion3.interests.InterestsFragment"
        android:label="Interests"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_interests" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_w"
        android:name="com.mApp.w.WFragment"
         />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_debug_menu"
        android:name="com.mApp.debugMenu.DebugMenuFragment"
        android:label="Debug Menu"
        tools:layout="@layout/activity_debug_menu" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_navigation_debug_menu_to_navigation_v_i"
            app:destination="@id/navigation_v_i" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_navigation_debug_menu_to_navigation_view_profile"
            app:destination="@id/navigation_view_profile"
              />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view_profile"
        android:name="com.mApp.viewProfile.ViewProfileFragment"
        android:label="View Profile"
        tools:layout="@layout/activity_view_profile" >
        <argument
            android:name="userId"
            app:argType="string" />
        <argument
            android:name="isLoggedInUser"
            app:argType="boolean" />
        <argument
            android:name="isSG"
            app:argType="boolean" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_navigation_view_profile_to_navigation_personal_info"
            app:destination="@id/navigation_personal_info"
              />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_navigation_view_profile_to_navigation_media_preview"
            app:destination="@id/navigation_media_preview"
              />
        <argument
            android:name="shouldShowTabBarOnClose"
            app:argType="boolean"
            android:defaultValue="false" />
        <argument
            android:name="shouldSetStatusBarDarkOnClose"
            app:argType="boolean"
            android:defaultValue="false" />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_v_i"
        android:name="com.mApp.editVersion3.vI.VIFragment"
        >
        <argument
            android:name="isNewUser"
            app:argType="boolean"
            android:defaultValue="false" />
        <argument
            android:name="isFromDebugMenu"
            app:argType="boolean"
            android:defaultValue="false" />
        <argument
            android:name="shouldShowTabBarOnClose"
            app:argType="boolean"
            android:defaultValue="false" />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_promo_events"
        android:name="com.mApp.promoEvents.PromoEventsFragment"
        android:label="Promo Events"
        tools:layout="@layout/activity_promo_events" >
        <argument
            android:name="photoUrl"
            app:argType="string"
            app:nullable="true"
            android:defaultValue="@null" />
        <argument
            android:name="firstName"
            app:argType="string"
            app:nullable="true"
            android:defaultValue="@null" />
        <argument
            android:name="promoCode"
            app:argType="string"
            app:nullable="true"
            android:defaultValue="@null" />
    </fragment>

    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_global_navigation_v_i"
        app:destination="@id/navigation_v_i"
         />

    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_global_navigation_edit_profile_home"
        app:destination="@id/navigation_edit_profile_home"
          />

    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_global_navigation_home"
        app:destination="@id/navigation_home"
        
        />

    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_global_navigation_swlm"
        app:destination="@id/navigation_swlm"
        
        />

    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_global_navigation_c"
        app:destination="@id/navigation_c"
        
        />

    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_global_navigation_d"
        app:destination="@id/navigation_d"
        
        />

    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_global_navigation_settings"
        app:destination="@id/navigation_account"
        
        />
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_global_navigation_mup_settings"
        app:destination="@id/navigation_mup_settings"
        
        />
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_global_navigation_personal_info"
        app:destination="@id/navigation_personal_info"
         />
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_global_navigation_d_account"
        app:destination="@id/navigation_d_account"
          />
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_global_navigation_view_profile"
        app:destination="@id/navigation_view_profile"
        />
</navigation>
```

I already tried to fix this by adding this code to all of my fragments and activities but it didn't fix it:

```
override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
        outState.clear()
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
    }
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: There are many reasons that can cause that, pls check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11451393/what-to-do-on-transactiontoolargeexception) out. Side note, use `FragmentContainerView` instead of fragment for the `NavHostFragment`

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to do the FragmentContainerView with the NavHostFragment? I thought FragmentContainerView was for compose. I have not converted my app fully to compose. the main activity is still using binding/xml

Comment: Just replace the `<fragment` tag with `<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView` in the main activity xml file