# Jetpack Glance Widget - android.os.TransactionTooLargeException error when using LazyColumn

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-widget, glance-appwidget, glance

I'm new to android development and Jetpack Compose. The Glance framework is my first introduction to it. I am currently building a glance widget that uses `LazyColumn` to display a list of data. If the number of items is small, it works fine, but for the list with more items, I get the following errors and crashes from time to time

```
!!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 539512)
Widget host dead: HostId{user:0, app:10162, hostId:1024, pkg:com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher}
android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 539512 bytes
    at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
    at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(BinderProxy.java:584)
    at com.android.internal.appwidget.IAppWidgetHost$Stub$Proxy.updateAppWidget(IAppWidgetHost.java:182)
    at com.android.server.appwidget.AppWidgetServiceImpl.handleNotifyUpdateAppWidget(AppWidgetServiceImpl.java:2071)
    at com.android.server.appwidget.AppWidgetServiceImpl.-$$Nest$mhandleNotifyUpdateAppWidget(AppWidgetServiceImpl.java:0)
    at com.android.server.appwidget.AppWidgetServiceImpl$CallbackHandler.handleMessage(AppWidgetServiceImpl.java:3856)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
    at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:46)
```

I've tried trimming the size of the list to make it smaller (currently, I've limited it to around 50 items), and it has been functioning well for a while. However, after a slight adjustment to the widget's code UI (Wrapping my widget with `GlanceTheme`), it now starts to crash again. I could trim the list further, but I'd love to know if there are other ways to avoid this issue as well. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What to do on TransactionTooLargeException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11451393/what-to-do-on-transactiontoolargeexception)

Comment: Thanks @tomerpacific – The link provided is informative for understanding the situation. However, I'm afraid I couldn't apply the solution they suggested, as it seems to me that the part to be modified is managed by the Glance framework (though I might be wrong). It appears that the best solution now is to ensure not to include too many views in the widget.  Your input is appreciated!